# Erratic behavior loading 2 JSON eventsources (one must be background events)

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am receiving an erratic behavior of the events when I load two `eventSources` and one of them is defined with rendering: background.

The generated JSONs are correct, since when defining the two `eventSources` with the normal rendering, everything works correctly.

The indicated behavior includes these symptoms:

- Some Events that are not rendered (they always disappear from the calendar **that is not background** and not appear in DOM)
- Background events that appear as normal events
- In each press of previous / next the behavior can be different.

This is my code to load the events:

```
$('#workshifts_ocupations_calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  eventSources: [
    {
      id: "workshiftSource", 
      url: '<?= base_url(); ?>turno/ajax_load_workshifts_by_installation/'+installation,
      editable:true,
      success: function(){
        console.log("turnos");
      }
    },
    {
      id: "backSource",
      url: '<?= base_url(); ?>ocupacion/ajax_load_ocupations_by_installation/'+installation,
      rendering: 'background',
      editable:false,
      success: function(){
        console.log("fondos");
      }
    }
  ],
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    // Si es background - Mostramos el título.
    if(event.source.rendering == "background"){
      element.html('<span class="backgroundEventsTitle">' + event.title + "</span>");
    }
  },
  locale: 'es',
  themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
  minTime: '07:00:00',
  maxTime: '23:00:00',
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
  slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
  selectable: true,
  allDaySlot: false,
  selectConstraint:{
    start: '07:00',
    end: '23:00',
  },
  eventConstraint:{
    start: '07:00',
    end: '23:00',
  },
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }

});
```

Here attach screenshots of the errors, **produced pressing next and preview buttons** (no reloading page).

behavior 1:
[image: behavior 1]

behavior 2:
[image: behavior 2]

**Repeat**: if I use normal rendering in both event sources, this issue does not occur.

FullCalendar v3.9.0

[Here is the background JSON](https://pastebin.com/Sgi0K7QA)

[Here is the normal events JSON](https://pastebin.com/GDuJhB17)

Comment: please provide sample JSON for each of the feeds which would demonstrate the problem. Right now, we can't reproduce your issue since we don't have access to your PHP endpoints in order to test. Also please let us know what version of fullCalendar you're using. Thanks.

Comment: Post edit with your requirements, thanks @ADyson

Comment: Thankyou. See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/118/ - this is the version where nothing is rendered as backgound. It works fine as far as I can see. Obviously I had to replace your data source with dummy static endpoints which return your sample data, but that's the only difference as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Here's the version where the background rendering is added: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/119/ . I can see the issue where the first item of each view is rendered as a normal event when it shouldn't. Not sure what's causing that, let me have a think. I can't reproduce the other issue in your screenshot (where the background event renders correctly but the non-background event disappears).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

You have an ID conflict across your two data sources. In your "normal" (non-background) data you have 5 events with IDs from 1 to 5. In your "background" source you also have 4 events with IDs 2 to 5. These conflict with the IDs in the other data source. It appears that this causes fullCalendar to get confused and assume that these are linked to the events in the "normal" data source with the same ID and therefore it appears to decide that they cannot be rendered as background events.

Whether this is a bug in fullCalendar I'm not entirely sure - you'd have to ask the programmers what their intent was. It's certainly possible in fullCalendar to have multiple events with the same ID and there a couple of scenarios where this is useful.

However if, as in your case, the events are totally unrelated, it's probabably not a good idea to give them the same IDs. As soon as you change the IDs, the problem goes away:

Example of modified background events:

```
{
    "id": "2000",
    "title": "At. Balearicus (perpe lui)",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF40D1",
    "borderColor": "#eb2cbd",
    "start": "2018-08-20 09:00:00",
    "end": "2018-08-20 10:00:00"
},
{
    "id": "3000",
    "title": "At. Balearicus (perpe lui)",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF40D1",
    "borderColor": "#eb2cbd",
    "start": "2018-08-27 09:00:00",
    "end": "2018-08-27 10:00:00"
},
{
    "id": "40000",
    "title": "At. Balearicus (perpe lui)",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF40D1",
    "borderColor": "#eb2cbd",
    "start": "2018-09-03 09:00:00",
    "end": "2018-09-03 10:00:00"
},
{
    "id": "5000",
    "title": "At. Balearicus (perpe lui)",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF40D1",
    "borderColor": "#eb2cbd",
    "start": "2018-09-10 09:00:00",
    "end": "2018-09-10 10:00:00"
},
```

Working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/135/

Comment: Ohhh, thanks! That's the problem!!

Actually, the events come from two different database tables (they are two types of events) and therefore the IDs coincide.

Thanks for the answer, I'll look for how I fix it

Comment: If you can't change the IDs, one option is to put them in a custom field in your event JSON e.g `serverID` or something. Then you've got a way to relate the event back to the database, but fullCalendar won't try to use it for anything (it will just generate a random ID for the event for its own internal use instead).